# How to build libclang release 6.0

Tags: llvm, libclang

I'm trying to build libclang for the latest release 6.0.
As I understand I need to clone llvm repository and then to clone clang repository under `tools/clang` directory, run cmake command and then build libclang with `make liblcang`

during the build I get the following error :

> llvm/tools/clang/lib/Lex/PTHLexer.cpp:339:12: error: ‘HashString’ is
>   not a member of ‘llvm’

it seems that there is some kind of version mismatch
I checked out `release_60` branch for both repositories
Looked in LLVM and clang documentation and could not find how to match the versions.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved.
I had to pull again to the latest commit